# An equation with mod, like $5x \pmod 6 = 1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let's say I have an equation: $5x \pmod 6 = 1$. 
How can I calculate the result of this equation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since $\operatorname{gcd}(5,6)=1$, you can use Euler's theorem and say $x\equiv 5^{(2-1)(3-1)-1}\pmod 6$. If not, you can check the cases with more or less ease. Another way is using the euclidean algorithm to write $1=5m+6k$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you want is to solve is $5x\equiv 1\pmod 6$.

Multiplying both sides by 5, you get

$25x\equiv 5\pmod 6$

Since $25\equiv 1 \pmod 6$,

So $x\equiv 5\pmod 6$.